# Spring Web App - Refreshing data routinely

Tags: java, spring, web-applications

I'm currently developing an online banking application where you can buy stocks. It is being built with spring boot and the front-end is html/css.

I am using the YahooFinance API to get stock quotes but I need to refresh my page to get the live stock quotes, how can I automatically update the page every 30 seconds to get the new prices for each stock?

Also, is there a way I could implement this using Threads?

Banking Controller

```
    @GetMapping("/banking/stocks")
public String stocks(Model model) {

    model.addAttribute("stock", new StockDto());
    try {
        List<Stock> stocks = stockService.getDefaultStocks();
        model.addAttribute("stocks", stocks);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "stocks.html";
}
```

StockServiceImpl:

```
@Service
public class StockServiceImpl implements StockService {

private String[] startingStocks = { "AAPL", "BABA", "MSFT", "AXP", "BA", "AMD", "TSLA", "MA", "SHOP", "GOOGL",
        "KL" };

@Override
public Stock getStock(String stockName) throws IOException {
    Stock stock = YahooFinance.get(stockName);
    return stock;
}

@Override
public Map<String, Stock> getStock(String[] s) throws IOException {
    Map<String, Stock> stocks = YahooFinance.get(s);
    return stocks;
}

@Override
public List<Stock> getDefaultStocks() throws IOException {
     Map<String, Stock> stocks = YahooFinance.get(startingStocks);
     List<Stock> stockList = new ArrayList<Stock>();
     for(String s : startingStocks) {
         stockList.add(stocks.get(s));
     }
    return stockList;
}
```

}

HTML Page For Displaying Stocks:

```
<main class='main-content bgc-grey-100'>
        <div id='mainContent'>
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <br>
                <h4 class="c-grey-900 mT-10 mB-30">Stock Table</h4>
                <form action="#" th:object="${stock}" th:action="@{/banking/stock-search}"
                    method="POST" class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
                    <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search"
                        th:field="*{name}" placeholder="Search Stock"
                        aria-label="Search">
                    <button class="btn btn-outline-primary my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
                </form>

                <br>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="bgc-white bd bdrs-3 p-20 mB-20">
                            <table id="dataTable" class="table table-striped table-bordered"
                                cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>Ticker</th>
                                        <th>Trade</th>
                                        <th>Name</th>
                                        <th>Price</th>
                                        <th>(%) Change</th>
                                        <th>Div Yield (%)</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tfoot>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>Ticker</th>
                                        <th>Trade</th>
                                        <th>Name</th>
                                        <th>Price</th>
                                        <th>(%) Change</th>
                                        <th>Div Yield (%)</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </tfoot>
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr th:each="stock : ${stocks}">
                                        <td th:text="${stock.getSymbol()}"></td>
                                            <td>
                                             <form action="#" th:action="@{/banking/stocks/} + ${stock.symbol}" method="get">
                                                 <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" th:id="'table_entry_childs_button_' + ${stock.symbol}" type="submit">
                                                    <i>Trade</i>
                                                  </button>
                                             </form>
                                         </td>
                                        <td th:text="${stock.getName()}"></td>
                                        <td th:text="${stock.getQuote().getPrice()}"></td>
                                        <td th:class="${stock.getQuote().getChangeInPercent() > 0 ? 'text-success' : 'text-danger'}" th:text="${stock.getQuote().getChangeInPercent() + '%'} "></td>
                                        <td th:if="${stock.getDividend().getAnnualYield() != null}" th:text="${stock.getDividend().getAnnualYield() + '%'}">0.00%</td>
                                        <td th:if="${stock.getDividend().getAnnualYield() == null}" >0.00%</td>     
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </main>
```

Comment: I need more information?  How are you passing this information from Sprintboot to your front-end (Html/Css) part?  I am curious.  Kindly show some code

Comment: Added the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can exploit STOMP protocol and web sockets using spring boot.
For reference:
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-websockets-send-message-to-user

on back end side you can use

```
@Autowired
SimpMessagingTemplate messagetemplate;

public void somemethod(String strParam){
 while (true){
    // build string or json whatever you need to send
    messagetemplate.convertAndSend("/blabla/blabla",strParam);
    Thread.sleep(30*1000);
 }
```

}

on front end side you have to use stomp.js

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/stomp.js/2.3.3/stomp.js"> 

<script type="text/javascript">
function load(){
   
   var stompClient = Stomp.client("ws://localhost:8080/ws");
   stompClient.connect({}, function (frame) {
    
       stompClient.subscribe('/blabla/blabla', function (message) {
         
        // do something here
       });
   });
}
```

lastly, part of html where you want to call on load

```
<html>
  <body  onload="load()">
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for the response! What does the folllowing do:
  stompClient.subscribe('/blabla/blabla', function (message) {
         
        // do something here
       });

And what is supposed to be put inside "//do something here" ?

Comment: subscribe(destination, callback) function subscribes with the destination. You can receive synchronous messages on 'destination', the "blabla/blabla" is the destination,  on second argument we are passing function to manipulate the callback message.  if you have noted we  already have bound our messages with 'destination' on server side spring object, that message you will recieve in  callback.  Second concern : for  "//do something here" you can you append you received message with html body. You can append using jquery.  for example $( ".bodyclass" ).append( "<p>your recieved message</p>" );

Comment: I see. But what if the message I am appending is a list of objects? Not just a String message. How would I loop through all of that information in my html body as a table of data? If you look at the HTML I provided above, you can notice that I use Spring to pass a list of stocks: <tr th:each="stock : ${stocks}">

How would I pass the list of stocks via jquery?

Comment: i think you are using thymeleaf , in that case the you  do need to setup attributes on backend side and return the page. i wrote my answer before you upload your code, you do not need to use STOMP

Comment: I have already set up the model attributes which pass the data to the front-end only at the start of the program, but how do I routinely pass it throughout program execution? I want the data on the front-end to continuously update? Would I need to use @Scheduled?

Answer (score 0):

You can create an @Scheduled method that can call this API request every 30 seconds to get data and update your Front-End.

```
@Scheduled(fixedRate = 30000)
public void updateStocksElement() {
  
  //Call your /banking/stocks rest endpoint    

}
```

https://spring.io/guides/gs/scheduling-tasks/